# Non differentiable loss function train with actor critic style

Tags: objective-functions, optimization, actor-critic-methods

I'm working on a project where a non differentiable loss is there. I'm thinking about how should I deal with them.

My model is a very big lstm model (about 1M parameter), and after 500 steps (not sure if it's enough) of [differential evolution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_evolution), the loss didn't decrease at all.

I'm thinking that actor critic can see as follows:
The policy network updates by value function, which is calculated from a reward estimator (Critic).

I'm wondering if I can take the thought of "estimator", and use it on loss estimation, then I can replace the non differentiable loss as that estimator, then also train the estimator each step. Maybe someone has already done that, if so, I want to know the name of the method.

Comment: what's your loss? what differential evolution method did you use? CE/CMA-ES?

Comment: The part make the loss function not differentiable is "argmax" and "split the list by a special element". And I think DE is an algorithm just like cma-es.

Comment: i mean you can definitely try reinforce, not quite sure how to help without a formal definition of the loss